# How to print multiple values for a true if statement in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, leap-year

```
package leapYear;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class leapYear {

    public static void main (String[] args){

    String yearInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year here: ");
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(yearInput);
    int year = inputScanner.nextInt();
    inputScanner.close();

    boolean leapYear = false;
    {

    if (year % 400 == 0)
    {
        leapYear = true;
    }

    else if (year % 100 == 0)
    {
        leapYear = false;
    }

    else if (year % 4 == 0)
    {
        leapYear = true;
    }

    else
    {
        leapYear = false;
    }

    if (leapYear)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, year + " IS a leap year!");

    else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, year + " is NOT a leap year!");
    }
}
}
```

Basically what I want to try to do, is to put in a year between say, 500-1000, and for the program to print every single leap year in that time period. I'm new to coding and have no idea how to go about this. Thanks.

Comment: 1. Write a function isLeapYear that takes a year as input, and returns `true` or `false`. 2. Write a loop to loop over the years. 3) Have that loop call that function.

Comment: You posted some code, now you should explain which part is trying to do the thing you described and explain which specific part is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Hint: class names start UpperCase. Always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simple put your code into some kind of loop:

```
for (int year = 500; year <= 1000; year++) {
 and here comes the code you already wrote
```

Of course, you might want to "beautify" things; by asking the user to provide the "lower" and "upper" limits of that loop:

```
for (int year = lowerLimitFromUser; year <= upperLimitFromUser; year++) {
```

In other words: the next concept that you want to study is about using the [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

And of course: to get their easily, you *start* by creating a helper method like

```
boolean isLeapYear(int year)
```

that you can call from within your loop. (ideally you first change your code to use that new method; to test that the restructuring didn't break the logic).

Answer (score 1):

Here this example is more along the lines of what you could do with a range of dates please adapt it as you like this is just a example as it does not take all the cases into account.

In this example I use a for loop to loop through the rage to see if there are any leap years then flag it to true.

You should look in to using methods to perform functions instead of having everything in the main method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class StackStuff {


    public static void main (String[] args){
    int yearStart  = 0,yearEnd=0,year=0;
    String yearInput;
    boolean isLeap = false;
    String[] possibleValues = {"Year Range","Single Year" };
    String selectedValue = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Choose one",
    "Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);

    if (selectedValue==possibleValues[0]){

        String yearInputStart = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the starting year here: ");
        String yearInputEnd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the ending year here: ");
        Scanner inputScannerStart = new Scanner(yearInputStart);
        Scanner inputScannerEnd = new Scanner(yearInputEnd);
        yearStart = inputScannerStart.nextInt();
        yearEnd = inputScannerEnd.nextInt();
        inputScannerStart.close();
        inputScannerEnd.close();
        for (int i = yearStart ; i <= yearEnd;i++){
            if (i % 4 == 0){
                 isLeap = true;
                break;
            }else {
                isLeap = false;
            }

        }
        if(isLeap){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There are leap years in this range");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," There are no leap years in this range");
        }


    }else{
        yearInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year here: ");
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(yearInput);
        year = inputScanner.nextInt();
        inputScanner.close();
        if (year% 4 == 0){
             isLeap = true;
        }
        else{
            isLeap = false;
        }

        if(isLeap){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is a leap year");
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is not a leap year");
        }
    }


  }

}
```